# Error with output in Java

Tags: java, symbol-not-found

I have this code

```
public class MemSim {

    public static final int NUM_PAGES = MemParam.NUM_PAGES;
    public static final int NUM_PROGRAMS = MemParam.NUM_PROGRAMS;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = MemParam.MAX_SIZE;
    public static final int PAGE_SIZE = MemParam.PAGE_SIZE;

    public void PageUsage(int sval, int eval) {

        sval = 0;
        eval = NUM_PAGES - 1;

        System.out.println(sval, eval);

    }
}
```

And I am getting the error message:

```
MemSim.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method println(int,int)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
System.out.println(sval , eval);
```

Comment: Why the huge blocks of blank lines for white space?  It won't fix broken code, nor make working code run faster, and one is enough for people.

Comment: Oh sorry I was not paying enough attention when I was posting it. And I'm just asking for help with error handling, not for you to do any of my work for me. I am just stuck and need some help

Comment: Try System.out.println(sval + " " + eval);

Comment: There is no version of `println` that takes two integers:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: That worked, put that as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: I strongly recommend that you become good friends with the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) and get yourself a IDE that provides method looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All signatures of System.out.println() take a single parameter, but you are passing two.

What IDE are you using? A decent IDE should have flagged this for you.

If you're not using an IDE, check the Java docs for valid classes and methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: +1 Yes, agree with Darius. Good IDE should have pointed this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try `System.out.println(sval + " " + eval);`? Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` has only one argument. If you wish to display both the values try this way

```
System.out.println("sval="+sval+" eval="+eval);
```